# .NET 4.5: ASP Menu Item value displaying as a link?

Tags: asp.net

In my code below the asp menu item value property is actually rendering as link text!

```
<asp:Menu ID="menuTop" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="menuselected" SkipLinkText="">
   <Items>
      <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" ImageUrl="~/images/Menu_Home.jpg" Value="Home" />
      <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Contact.aspx" ImageUrl="~/images/Menu_Contact.jpg" Value="Contact"/>
   </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

According to the MSDN reference located at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitem.value.aspx

> The Value property is used to supplement the Text property by storing
>   any additional data associated with the menu item. This value is not
>   displayed in the control and is commonly used to store data for
>   handling postback events.

I need it to store values, why is it displaying as link text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. Looks like you need to set the Text value to "" and that prevents the value from displaying as text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
<asp:Menu ID="menuTop" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="menuselected" SkipLinkText="">
    <Items>
       <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" ImageUrl="~/images/Menu_Home.jpg" Value="Home" Text="" />
       <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Contact.aspx" ImageUrl="~/images/Menu_Contact.jpg" Value="Contact" Text=""/>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```